# Installing Docker On Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, docker

Following the instruction on [Install Docker's EE on Windows Server](https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/), I installed docker. However, during the *test your docker step* where I entered in 
`docker container run hello-world:nanoserver`, I'm getting the following exception:

> docker: 'container' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'.

This is alarming because I'm not sure if docker was installed correctly. When I look at the version `docker version`, I get the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory: 'container' is not a docker command. Did you try `docker run hello-world:nanoserver`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn’t recognize run as a command

Comment: The link you posted does not work. So at this point there is nothing to go on here.

Comment: The link I post was written by the docker team.

Comment: Try to click the link in your post above!

Comment: What's wrong with it? It goes to https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/. As, it should!

Answer (score 0):

`docker container run hello-world:nanoserver`

Is a typo in that document.  It should just be:

`docker run hello-world:nanoserver`